# Value is out of bound node red reading float

Tags: node-red, modbus

I am testing a small application with node red, reading modbus data from a device, I observe that reads well the device data, but it keeps sending me an error ""TypeError: "value" argument is out of bounds"", I have this code in each of my read functions, and in each one appears the same error, I am reading a floating data from the buffer.

```
var pay = msg.payload.data;
var buf = Buffer.allocUnsafe(4);
buf.writeInt16BE(pay[1],2);
buf.writeInt16BE(pay[0],0);
msg.payload = buf.readFloatBE(0);
return msg;
```

[image: (Edit) This is the input argument and the error recived]

Comment: Please edit the question to include the `msg.payload.data` content so we can see what the input is.

Answer (score 0):

If you run this just in pure NodeJS you get the full error which is:

```
> buf.writeInt16BE(60009,2)
Uncaught:
RangeError [ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE]: The value of "value" is out of range. It must be >= -32768 and <= 32767. Received 60009
    at checkInt (internal/buffer.js:68:11)
    at writeU_Int16BE (internal/buffer.js:828:3)
    at Buffer.writeInt16BE (internal/buffer.js:890:10)
    at REPL39:1:5
    at Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:120:18)
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:442:29)
    at bound (domain.js:427:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:440:12)
    at REPLServer.onLine (repl.js:777:10)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:326:22) {
  code: 'ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE'
}
```

This error should also have been printed to the Node-RED logs.

`60009` is too big to be a 16bit signed integer so can't be written to the buffer with `writeInt16BE()`.

It could be written with `writeUInt16BE()` or I suspect you will do better just reading the float directly from the buffer already in the msg object.

```
msg.payload = msg.payload.buffer.readFloatBE()
```