# NodeRed modbus data to float

Tags: arrays, buffer, node-red, modbus

I am a beginner with Node-Red and I would like to read the data of a meter via modbus and then display it in float format

[image]

With Modbus-Read node I'm getting this data:

[image]

How can I to convert in a float number like 407.555

thanks in advance for the help

**Update 06/11/2021:** I'tryng to convert the array recived from modbus but the result is wrong.
I try tu use a function like this:

```
let pay = msg.payload;
const buf = Buffer.allocUnsafe(4);

buf.writeInt16BE(pay[0],2);
buf.writeInt16BE(pay[1],0);

msg.payload = buf.readFloatBE(0);
return msg;
```

In NodeRed if I add a debug I can read
0x1f85
0xb40

so is the same reading using a different modbus reader but the conversion in nodered with the function is 3.700156759202689e-32 and the value right is 2.18

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66391528/value-is-out-of-bound-node-red-reading-float

Comment: @MadCat can you update your question to be a bit more specific? do you mean you want to convert the array of data values read from modbus to float? or is the meter providing float values, but node-red-contrib-modbus is not converting data properly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56257673/reading-32-bit-float-from-modbus-tcp-using-node-red

Comment: @Nicolas.V thankyou for your reply I try to add some more information